# is this permutation or combination?

Tags: set, combinations, permutation

I am bit struggling to understand the set theory.

I know that there are combinations and permutations to choose sets from a given input.

For example, I have 3 buttons A, B, and C to retrieve data from each basket A, B, and C.

If I want to retrieve data from A and B then I must select A and B button.

to retrieve data from A and C then I must select A and C.

to retrieve data from A, B, and C then I must select all three buttons.

Since it is a button to retrieve data, the sequence would not matter such that AB = BA.

Then, I will have

```
A
B
C
AB
AC
BC
ABC
```

I thought this was a permutation. But then I am getting a total of 7 instead of 6.
I really feel like I am not getting what combinations and permutations are.

Can someone explain what this is?

Answer (score 0):

A permutation of an ordered set is an arrangement of its elements. All the permutations of the set {A,B,C} are

```
(A,B,C)
(A,C,B)
(C,A,B)
(C,B,A)
(B,C,A)
(B,A,C)
```

For a set of N elements there are N! permutations.

In contrast, a combination is a selection of k elements from a set of N elements. Order does not play a role here. k can vary between 0 and N. For a fixed k there are N!/(k!(N-k)!) combinations. Summing all of them up gives a total of 2^N combinations. The eight possible combinations of {A,B,C} are

```
{}
{A}
{B}
{C}
{A,B}
{A,C}
{B,C}
{A,B,C}
```